# Python 3.6 can't import from kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, ubuntu-16.04

I've been trying to run any python script with kivy, but I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'` everytime I try to import.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, and running Python 3.6.5.

I've installed kivy according to the official website (https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html), and also tried to `pip3 install` it. It installs without a problem, but then gives the same error when I try to run a script.

For example, running the example suggested on the official website (`$ python3 -c "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('kivy', '../share/kivy-examples'))` returns the following traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 346, in get_provider
        module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq] KeyError: 'kivy'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1136, in resource_filename
        return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 348, in get_provider
        __import__(moduleOrReq) 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'
```

Any sugestions on why I get this error, and on how I could fix it?

Comment: I am having similar issue. Any luck so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try following [this:](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-lubuntu-oneiric-and-above%20this:)

You may need to install

```
pip install numpy
pip install Cython==0.27.3
```